# Setting a size for each id in a php session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Ok I have been fighting this for quite a while and it has been really irritating. So I need some help.

I have a drop down that allows the user to select a size for the picture they are purchasing. This value needs to saved in a php session and assigned to that particular picture, allowing the user to choose multiple pictures with a different size on each picture.

I am submitting the drop down through ajax when the user selects the size:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#sizeConfirm').click(function() {
        var size = $("#sizeSelector option:selected").val(); 
        var id = $("#idInput").val();
        $("#sizeId"+id).html(size);

        var dataString = 'size='+ size + '&id='+id;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST", 
            url: "../functions/size-functions.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {

            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

And this submits to the following script:

```
<?php 

   session_start();

   $id = $_POST['id'];

   $_SESSION['size'][$id] = $_POST['size'];

?>
```

I have used the set up in the code above for adding the pictures to the shopping cart. I placed: `<?php echo $_SESSION['size']; ?>` on the same page the java script is placed and I receive: `Array` as a result of that.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me out?

Basically, I want to be able to do the following:

```
User selects Category  -- This works 
  User selects Picture -- This works  
    User select size on cart page -- This is what the question is about.
```

If it helps the select option looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="sizeSelector">
    <option>Select a Size</option>
    <option>4x4</option>
    <option>4x6</option>
    <option>5x7</option>
    <option>6x6</option>
    <option>8x8</option>
    <option>8x10</option>
    <option>8x12</option>
    <option>10x12</option>
    <option>12x16</option>
    <option>4x18</option>                   
</select>
```

I wasn't sure exactly what to put in this question -- So if you believe I am missing something that would require the solution to be found, simply comment and tell me and I will add it. Thank you!

Comment: $_SESSION['size'] is an array, with each size under the id key. use `print_r($_SESSION)` to see the full array

Comment: Oh okay, so you would just do a `foreach` to display just the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are assigning the session as an array `$_SESSION['size'][$id]`.

To display the results, try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = "1";//$_POST['id'];
$size="14";//$_POST['size'];
$_SESSION['size'][$id] = $size;
//print_r($_SESSION['size']);


echo $_SESSION['size'][$id];
?>
```

Edit:
This would display the selected size, for each product they are viewing.

Comment: Ok so I got that displayed out. Now I need to get it so it displays under the `size` row in my table of items "shopping cart" take a look at the screen shot to understand better. http://alphahq.org/Capture.PNG

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...Is this the user' cart? If so, under the size bit - Simply replace the label with the size they have selected. Otherwise I'm confused.

Comment: I guess what I really should be asking is.... How do you break the array up to display each independent id and size? Right now I am using a foreach to achieve that was on the screenshot. But that displays all of them.

Comment: Ok whilst listing the product, I assume you are getting the image using the product id(?) and other details...Using the ID, simply put $id="Whatever ID you are using, to retrieve the image and other info";echo $_SESSION['size'][$id'];